# What is the origin of the term "kinematic" in RTK?

Tags: gps

Where does "Kinematic" in "Real Time Kinematic" (RTK) come from?

Most litterature on RTK explains that it stands for Real Time Kinematic, but not why that name is used instead of something more descriptive like "real time carrier phase differential positioning".

Comment: It's interesting that the [Wikipedia entry for RTK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_kinematic_positioning) doesn't link to its own entry for [kinematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinematics).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some searching it seems that "kinematic" comes from the original application of land surveying, where kinematic surveying seems to mean that one measurement station is continously tracked while moving [[1](https://water.usgs.gov/osw/gps/)][[2](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2FBFb0011342.pdf)].